# How do I convert IEnumerable<Enum> to Enum in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, enums, ienumerable

I've parsed several strings into Enum flags but can't see a neat way of merging them into a single Enum bitfield.

The method I'm using loops through the string values then |= the casted values to the Enum object, like so:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum { None = 0, First = 1, Second = 2, Third = 4 }
...

string[] flags = { "First", "Third" };
MyEnum e = MyEnum.None;

foreach (string flag in flags)
    e |= (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), flag, true);
```

I've tried using a Select method to convert to my Enum type, but then I'm stuck with `IEnumerable<MyEnum>`. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's an `IEnumerable<string>`, not an `IEnumerable<Enum>`.

Comment: @BoltClock, the code example shows a string array, but using `flags.select(flag => (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), flag, true))` does return an `IEnumerable<Enum>` and that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, from an `IEnumerable<MyEnum>` you can use:

```
MyEnum result = parsed.Aggregate((current, next) => current | next);
```

or in order to accommodate an empty sequence:

```
MyEnum result = parsed.Aggregate(MyEnum.None, (current, next) => current | next);
```

It's basically the same thing as you've already got, admittedly...

So overall, the code would be:

```
MyEnum result = flags.Select(x => (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), x))
                     .Aggregate(MyEnum.None, (current, next) => current | next);
```

(You can perform it in a single `Aggregate` call as per Guffa's answer, but personally I think I'd keep the two separate, for clarity. It's a personal preference though.)

Note that my [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) project makes enum handling somewhat more pleasant, and you can also use the generic [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) method in .NET 4.

So for example, using Unconstrained Melody you could use:

```
MyEnum result = flags.Select(x => Enums.ParseName<MyEnum>(x))
                     .Aggregate(MyEnum.None, (current, next) => current | next);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Aggregate` method to put the flags together:

```
MyEnum e = flags
  .Select(s => (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), s, true))
  .Aggregate(MyEnum.None, (f, n) => f | n);
```