# Linq Aggregate function return wrong Flags Enum

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to convert an array of Enum in a Flags Enum by usign the Aggregate function in Linq but it returns the wrong enum.
I've also tried with a classic foreach iterator but the result is the same.
Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFlagsEnum
{
    All,
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F
}

public static void Main()
{
    var array=new MyFlagsEnum[] {MyFlagsEnum.B,MyFlagsEnum.C,MyFlagsEnum.D,MyFlagsEnum.E,MyFlagsEnum.F};
    var flagsenum =array.Aggregate(MyFlagsEnum.All,(x,y)=>x|y);
    MyFlagsEnum iterator = 0;
    foreach (var item in array)
        iterator |= item;   
    Console.WriteLine("array:"+string.Join(" ",array));
    Console.WriteLine("iterator:"+string.Join(" ",iterator));
    Console.WriteLine("flags Enum:" +flagsenum);
}
```

the result is

```
array:B C D E F
iterator:A, F 
flags Enum:A, F
```

Here a working example on [Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ArrJgR)

I'm expected as result the same of the array, but it return A,F.
How can I compose the correct Flagged Enum form this Array?

I've take the the code from these questions

[How do I convert IEnumerable to Enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972937/how-do-i-convert-ienumerableenum-to-enum-in-c)

[Converting array of enum values to flags enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203881/converting-array-of-enum-values-to-flags-enum)

but applied to my case does not work?
What I'm doing wrong?